# Creating Sub Calendars that Feed a subset of Events to Master Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I need to create a site where designated users can create events for their own respective calendars, which then get approved by a supervisor, and afterwards can be optionally pushed up to a master calendar.

Is there a good way to do this?

*Forgive me if this question is out of place, this is my first time on this SE. I spend quite a bit of time on SO.*

Comment: What SharePoint version?? Have a look at calendar overlays. You can create views in any calendar and then overlay those views on a master calendar.

Comment: Sharepoint 2007

Comment: Forget Calendar overlays then. It's always a good idea to state your version and license, because the differences between 2007/2010/2013 and Foundation/Standard/Enterprise are immense.